# How to make bootstrap css input add-on button and error span look good

Tags: html, css, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use a combo input checkbox that also shows required (angular) validation error when it's missing, but I cannot get the checkbox add-on and the help-block to play nice.  Here's the markup:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': addressForm.street.$invalid && !addressForm.street.$pristine}">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Street" name="street" class="form-control" ng-model="address.street" required>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="addressForm.street.$invalid && !addressForm.street.$pristine">Required</span>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="address.listAddress"> List
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks fine when there's no error:
[image]

But not fine when there is an error:
[image]

I've tried reordering, changing the error span to a div, inserting br, etc.  Any help is much obliged.  Would be even happier if it can be down without tons more markup (new to html/css and it's kind of amazing to me how so many chars are required to say something that seems simple).

Comment: Can you move the required span outside of the `input-group` div?

Comment: yes.  wow!  can you write that as an answer so I can mark correct?   Thanks.  Amazing how many re-orderings I tried without thinking of that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the required span outside of the `input-group` div.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <span class="help-block" ng-show="addressForm.street.$invalid && !addressForm.street.$pristine">Required</span>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Street" name="street" class="form-control" ng-model="address.street" required>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="address.listAddress"> List
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```